# PayUMoney payment gateway issue

Tags: ios, iphone, payu

I have to integrate PayUMoney payment gateway in my iOS app. They don't have SDK for iOS. So I have to load some web URL in webview for the payment. My parameters are

```
int i = arc4random() % 9999999999;
NSString *strHash = [self createSHA512:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%@",i,[NSDate date]]];// Generatehash512(rnd.ToString() + DateTime.Now);
NSString *txnid1 = [strHash substringToIndex:20];
NSLog(@"tnx1 id %@",txnid1);
NSString *key = @"JBZaLc";
NSString *amount = @"1000";
NSString *productInfo = @"Nice product";
NSString *firstname = @"Mani";
NSString *email = @"mani.ingenius@gmail.com";
NSString *phone = @"1234566";
NSString *surl = @"www.google.com";
NSString *furl = @"www.google.com";
NSString *serviceprovider = @"payu_paisa";
NSString *action = @"https://test.payu.in/_payment";
NSString *hashValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5||||||salt",key,txnid1,amount,productInfo,firstname,email];
NSString *hash = [self createSHA512:hashValue];
NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:txnid1,key,amount,productInfo,firstname,email,phone,surl,furl,hash,serviceprovider,action, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"txnid",@"key",@"amount",@"productinfo",@"firstname",@"email",@"phone",@"surl",@"furl",@"hash",@"service_provider",@"action", nil]];
```

I have to use POST method with my test URL (`https://test.payu.in/_payment`) and need to pass parameters. I have all parameters with key and value in dictionary("parameters"). So I tried following code

```
 NSData *dataValue = [self getPropertiesAsData:parameters];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://test.payu.in/_payment"]];
    // Create a mutable copy of the immutable request and add more headers
    NSMutableURLRequest *mutableRequest = [request mutableCopy];
    [mutableRequest setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [mutableRequest setHTTPBody: dataValue];
    request = [mutableRequest copy];
    [_webviewSample loadRequest:request];


-(NSData *)getPropertiesAsData :(NSDictionary *)dict{
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData postData];
    [dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
            [body addValue:[obj stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"] forKey:key];
            }];
    return body;
}

-(NSString *)createSHA512:(NSString *)string
{
    const char *cstr = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:string.length];
    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA512(data.bytes, data.length, digest);
    NSMutableString* output = [NSMutableString  stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
    for(int i = 0; i < CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];
    return output;
}
```

But when I run this, it says "Mandatory parameter tnxid is missing". But I have passed the tnxid which you can see in parameters dictionary. If I pass everything correctly then result will be the webpage where user can select bank details, etc that I have to load it in my web view.

Please help me to find what I did wrong or what I should do to get correct result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69431/discussion-between-iphonemaclover-and-mani-murugan).

Comment: I am using your code but no luck, always getting error "Sorry, Some Problem Occurred". I am using: 
Post Url: https://test.payu.in/_payment
Test Key: JBZaLc
Test Salt: GQs7yium
Do i need to signup and get my own credentials from PayUMoney for Testing. 
I would be really thankful if you can guide me to the right path.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found answer successfully. My working code is listed below

```
int i = arc4random() % 9999999999;
    NSString *strHash = [self createSHA512:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%@",i,[NSDate date]]];// Generatehash512(rnd.ToString() + DateTime.Now);
    NSString *txnid1 = [strHash substringToIndex:20];
    NSLog(@"tnx1 id %@",txnid1);
    NSString *key = @"JBZaLc";
    NSString *amount = @"1000";
    NSString *productInfo = @"Nice product";
    NSString *firstname = @"Mani";
    NSString *email = @"mani.ingenius@gmail.com";
    NSString *phone = @"1234566";
    NSString *surl = @"www.google.com";
    NSString *furl = @"www.google.com";
    NSString *serviceprovider = @"payu_paisa";


    NSString *hashValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|||||||||||GQs7yium",key,txnid1,amount,productInfo,firstname,email];
    NSString *hash = [self createSHA512:hashValue];
    NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:txnid1,key,amount,productInfo,firstname,email,phone,surl,furl,hash,serviceprovider
                                                                    , nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"txnid",@"key",@"amount",@"productinfo",@"firstname",@"email",@"phone",@"surl",@"furl",@"hash",@"service_provider", nil]];
   __block NSString *post = @"";
    [parameters enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([post isEqualToString:@""]) {
            post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@",key,obj];
        }else{
            post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&%@=%@",post,key,obj];
        }

    }];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://test.payu.in/_payment"]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    [_webviewSample loadRequest:request];
```

then functions to be used

```
-(NSString *)createSHA512:(NSString *)string
{
    const char *cstr = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:string.length];
    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA512(data.bytes, (CC_LONG)data.length, digest);
    NSMutableString* output = [NSMutableString  stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
    for(int i = 0; i < CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];
    return output;
}
```

Comment: hello, you are using payUmonkey SALT and merchant key.
Did you use payUmoney? as i am working with PayUindia and its not working by key provided by them.Any help welcome

Comment: hello @iphonemaclover , I am using a same code and it will work fine in some cases. means if i used this key = "gtKFFx" and salt = "eCwWELxi' , it will not work. Please tell me what is the reason behind this.

Comment: @iphonemaclover , payUindia and payUmoney are different?

Comment: @SumitGarg sorry for being late reply, No they have both have same provider, but according to need merchant purchase payuindia or payumoney.

Comment: Where can I find sandbox credit card details for testing successfull  payment?

Comment: One can find test credentials here.
http://www.edugcet.in/franchisee_download/7c8660cce1870f606064ff76c258d76d.pdf

Answer (score 5):

Finally i resolved the issue regarding **PayU India** (*not payU,payU and payUindia have a slight difference as mention*) integration (above code is for payU Money help alot)
Download [github Repo here](https://github.com/dsrawat4u/PayUIndia_IOS_SDK)

**You only need to remove an extra parameter which is service_provider whose value is payu_paisa.**

```
int i = arc4random() % 9999999999;
    NSString *strHash = [self createSHA512:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%@",i,[NSDate date]]];// Generatehash512(rnd.ToString() + DateTime.Now);
    NSString *txnid1 = [strHash substringToIndex:20];
    NSLog(@"tnx1 id %@",txnid1);
    NSString *key = @"YOURKEY";
    NSString *salt = @"YOURSALTKEY";

    NSString *amount = @"100";
    NSString *productInfo = @"Niceproduct";
    NSString *firstname = @"Deepak";
    NSString *email = @"iphonemaclover@gmail.com";
    NSString *phone = @"9212138007";
    NSString *surl = @"www.google.com";
    NSString *furl = @"www.google.com";


    NSString *hashValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|||||||||||%@",key,txnid1,amount,productInfo,firstname,email,salt];
    NSString *hash = [self createSHA512:hashValue];
    NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:txnid1,key,amount,productInfo,firstname,email,phone,surl,furl,hash
                                                                    , nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"txnid",@"key",@"amount",@"productinfo",@"firstname",@"email",@"phone",@"surl",@"furl",@"hash", nil]];
   __block NSString *post = @"";
    [parameters enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([post isEqualToString:@""]) {
            post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@",key,obj];
        }else{
            post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&%@=%@",post,key,obj];
        }

    }];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://test.payu.in/_payment"]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    [_webviewSample loadRequest:request];
```

EDIT: how to handle URL payment is sucess or not

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
        if (web_view_PayU.isLoading)
        return;
    NSURL *requestURL = [[web_view_PayU request] URL];

    NSLog(@"requestURL=%@",requestURL);

    NSString *getStringFromUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",requestURL];

    if ([getStringFromUrl isEqualToString:@"https://test.payu.in/yoursucessurladdedhere "]||[getStringFromUrl isEqualToString:@"https://secure.payu.in/yoursucessurladdedhere "])
    {
       //SUCCESS ALERT
       //jump to place order API

    }
   else if ([getStringFromUrl isEqualToString:@"https://test.payu.in/yourfailureurladdedhere "]||[getStringFromUrl isEqualToString:@"https://secure.payu.in/yourfailureurladdedhere"])
    {
        // FAIL ALERT
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Sorry!" message:@"Your Order Not Successfull!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        alert.tag=2222;

        [alert show];
    }

}
```

For Android Integration of Pay U [check link--](https://github.com/pjtfernandes/PayUTestApp)

Comment: Can anyone tell how I will get to know that my payment is succeeded or failed ? The above code is working fine for me and showing payment screen, but what about payment result ? Please help me as I am desperate to the answer. I am stuck at this point.

Comment: Hello pratik, please check the github repo,it includes the code to handle the payment sucess of fail,quick hit,just check the sucess and fail url load at webview delegate method and according to it add your condition...hope it will help

Comment: Thanks you so much for your reply  iphonemaclover. I have implemented as per your example. But my main point is how I will know that payment succeeded or not in **-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView** method ? I have made request with checksum and everything using webview, but this is the point I have stuck.

Comment: check my edit answer now,simily compair the load url with the url u got it something url/urlfail or url/urlsucess just check if the url string contain it or not...

Comment: hi @iphonemaclover i have use you github example and try to run using my key but return error 404 page not fount plese help me bcz i need integrate payu payment in ios.

Comment: must confirm, you are using payu or payUindia,my example is for payUindia.
And must check your NSString *key = @"YOURKEY";
    NSString *salt = @"YOURSALTKEY"; is correct.

Comment: @DharmeshDhorajiya for only  <PayU> integration follow 
Mani murugan  accepted answer.

Comment: yes i have try both but i get 404 page error some problem occur like that @iphonemaclover

Comment: and i tried then ask question, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681781/payumoney-getway-error-occur-in-ios @iphonemaclover

Answer (score 4):

I mailed to the PayUMoney Technical team and got my answer why i am getting error "Sorry, Some Problem Occurred."

Got a quick reply for the Technical Team:

```
Recently, we have done some modifications in test environment due to which test key-JBZaLc and salt-GQs7yium will not work anymore.

In order to test the gateway using a test key and salt, kindly follow these steps:
1 - Go on https://test.payumoney.com
2 - Sign up as a merchant - use any of your valid email ids - kindly do not use a random email id.
3 - Complete the "Business Details"  - you may use PAN no. ABCDE1234F and DOB - 01/04/1990
4 - Complete "Bank Account Details" (You may use IFSC- ALLA0212632)
5 - Go to below mentioned location to get the Test Merchant Id :     
 Seller Dashboard -> Settings -> My account -> Profile Settings

Once you provide your test merchant id, we will approve it so that you can find your test key and salt at :
Seller Dashboard -> Settings -> My account -> Merchant Key - Salt
```

Download [Github Repository](https://github.com/surajwebo/payUmoney-Payment-Gateway/archive/master.zip)

Comment: hi @Suraj Mirajkar i have use above code but i return error 404 page not found and use this link https://test.payu.in/_payment please help.

Answer (score 0):

For swift Version

1) import into bridging header

** import CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h **

2) after

```
func sha512Hex( string: String) -> String {
    var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    if let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        let value =  data as NSData
        CC_SHA512(value.bytes, CC_LONG(data.count), &digest)

    }
    var digestHex = ""
    for index in 0..<Int(CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH) {
        digestHex += String(format: "%02x", digest[index])
    }

    return digestHex
}
```

3) install pod PlugNPlay

4) after follow step provided PlugNPlay