# Payumoney getway error occur in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, payu

I have integrate payumoney payment getway. But i get error in webView not load this https://test.payu.in/_payment testing url.

[image]

**And my code:**

```
 int i = arc4random() % 9999999999;
    NSString *strHash = [self createSHA512:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%@",i,[NSDate date]]];
    NSString *txnid1 = [strHash substringToIndex:20];
    NSLog(@"tnx1 id %@",txnid1);

    NSString *key = @"xxxxx"; // my key
    NSString* salt = @"xxxxxx"; // my salt key

    NSString *amount = @"1.00";
    NSString *productInfo = @"Nice product";
    NSString *firstname = @"Mani";
    NSString *email = @"mani.ingenius@gmail.com";
    NSString *phone = @"1234566";
    NSString *surl = @"http://www.google.com/";
    NSString *furl = @"http://www.github.in/";
    NSString *serviceprovider = @"payu_paisa";

    NSString *hashValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|||||||||||%@",key,txnid1,amount,productInfo,firstname,email,salt];


    NSString *hash = [self createSHA512:hashValue];
    NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:txnid1,key,amount,productInfo,firstname,email,phone,surl,furl,hash,serviceprovider
                                                                    , nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"txnid",@"key",@"amount",@"productinfo",@"firstname",@"email",@"phone",@"surl",@"furl",@"hash",@"service_provider", nil]];


    __block NSString *post = @"";
    [parameters enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([post isEqualToString:@""]) {
            post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@",key,obj];
        }else{
            post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&%@=%@",post,key,obj];
        }

    }];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://test.payu.in/_payment"]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    [web_view_PayU loadRequest:request];
```

i have refer this link [PayUMoney payment gateway issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27898349/payumoney-payment-gateway-issue) .And I have pass all parameter correct. I have not understand what i am wrong.

I get my merchant and salt key this following path

```
 Seller Dashboard -> Settings -> My account -> Merchant Key - Salt
```

Comment: please check answer,first test with below key provided,if it works perfectly then try with live keys and by setting live URL,hope it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found above my question solution. I have not pass "charset=utf-8" in `forHTTPHeaderField` field value.

pass this way parameter in url request.

```
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
```

old version without "charset=utf-8" work correct but latest code add "charset=utf-8" in url.

Answer (score 0):

For Test code use these keys:

```
NSString *key = @"JBZaLc";
NSString* salt = @"GQs7yium";
```

And ur Url

```
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://test.payu.in/_payment"]]];
```

NOTE: For live Use,replace KEY and SALT value with your own value.
& setURL with

```
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" https://secure.payu.in/_payment"]]];
```

Comment: this key is not valid i ask for support team. @iphonemaclover

Comment: yes now its not working and shows payUbiz so might they have change the code

Comment: any way to use this payment getway in ios? @ iphonemaclover

Answer (score 0):

NSString *serviceprovider = @"";

Leave the Service Provider field as blank. 
That should work.

Comment: try this but same problem.